# How to translate language in Qt on the fly

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I am using Translator and linguist to translate language in my application in Qt symbain, But I want to do this on the fly (on run time), I have tried the solution given by the developer network but it is not working for me

```
 #include "languagetranslator.h"
 #include "constants.h"
 #include <QSettings>
 #include <HelperClasses/Strings.h>
 #include <QTranslator>
#include <AppStatus/appstatus.h>
#include <QApplication>

QTranslator* LanguageTranslator::current = 0;

LanguageTranslator::LanguageTranslator(int& argc, char* argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv)
{

}


LanguageTranslator::~LanguageTranslator()
{
}

void LanguageTranslator::loadTranslation()
{
    QString language;
    language = AppStatus::getCurrentLanguage();
    loadTranslation(language);
    qDebug("language from laodtranslation = %s",language.toLatin1().data());
    //qDebug(language.toLatin1());
}

void LanguageTranslator::loadTranslation(QString language)
{
    //QApplication app;
    QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator(instance());
    translator->load(language);
    installTranslator(&translator);

    //exec();

}
```

It only works when I declared it in main.cpp and restart the application, I am also calling this method after selecting the new language  is there any thing that I am missing. I am following the following link http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dynamic_translation_in_Qt4_applications

Do I have to call the void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event) when setting new language

this is my changeEvent() method which I had declared in mainWindow from here I am calling setLanguage();

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
       // retranslate();
        setLanguage();
    }
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}



void MainWindow::setLanguage()
{
    QString myLanguage;
    int iIndex =  AppStatus::getSettingsData().at(3);
    switch(iIndex)
    {
    case ENGLISH:
        myLanguage = "language_en";
        break;
    case SPANISH:
        myLanguage = "language_es";
        break;
    }
    AppStatus::saveCurrentLanguage(myLanguage);

LanguageTranslator::loadTranslation(myLanguage);
}
```

from setLangauge() I am calling the languageTranslator()
IS there anything that I am missing;
This is my main class

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    LanguageTranslator app(argc, argv);
    QString lang = AppStatus::getCurrentLanguage();
    app.installTranslator(&translator);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setOrientation(MainWindow::ScreenOrientationLockPortrait);

    //About mainWindow;

#if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
    mainWindow.showMaximized();
#else
    mainWindow.show();

#endif

   // mainWindow.showFullScreen();
    app.connect(&app,SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()),&app,SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Don't call setLanguage() from within changeEvent()! You should call setLanguage() from wherever you can change the language. setLanguage() calls LanguageTranslator::loadTranslation() which calls QApplication::installTranslator() which creates a LanguageChange Event which is then caught in MainWindow::changeEvent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link you gave states:

> However, the basic principle is to override QWidget::changeEvent() in every widget which has to be aware of dynamic language changes.

This is required as `installTranslator()` will create a change event which will be sent to every single widget.
This means, if you want your MainWindow to be retranslated, you have to do:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
        // retranslate designer form (single inheritance approach)
        ui.retranslateUi(this);
    }

    // remember to call base class implementation
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}
```

You have to do this for every widget which has a translatable GUI

[Edit - Added comment as it was the actual answer to the question]

Don't call setLanguage() from within changeEvent()! You should call setLanguage() from wherever you can change the language. setLanguage() calls LanguageTranslator::loadTranslation() which calls QApplication::installTranslator() which creates a LanguageChange Event which is then caught in MainWindow::changeEvent

Comment: so if I have 3 widgets I have to right changeEvent() in each and every class, and also I am using stackWidget so how to implement changeEvent() on every page.

Comment: You have to implement changeEvent() in each of the three widgets. If you add these three widgets to the same QStackWidget, you don't have to change the QStackWidget. I am almost sure QStackWidget will forward the changeEvent() to its child widgets.

Comment: Is there any way to reload mainWindow every time I change language.

Comment: There is: Identify the code which shall be executed both during construction and when the language changes. Put that code into an own function and call that function from the constructor and from within changeEvent()

Comment: Thanks tim its working now... I wasn't calling setLanguage() from where I am setting my language.

Comment: It is showing "virtual void changeEvent(QEvent *)";  is a protected function in qwidget.h class, and if I make it public it shows QWidget::metric: Invalid metric command in Qt. How can I use changeEvent in my other Qwidgets ??

Comment: protected means you can not access it from other classes, but you can access it from subclasses. Just make it protected in the subclass and be sure the definition is exactly like in the base class. You cannot make a protected function public in a subclass in C++ (and any other language I guess)