# QT5: RetranslateUi does not retranslate view

Tags: qt, localization, qt5

I'm attempting to add dynamic localisation support to an application, however when calling `retranslateUi()` on the `MainWindow` nothing is translated.

I use the code below in a preferences dialog to set the localisation to use:

```
if(translator.load(QDir::toNativeSeparators("localisation/") + m_localisations.at(ui->languageOptionsBox->currentIndex()).name() + "_v1"))
    qDebug() << "Loaded translation";
else
    qDebug() << "Translation not loaded";

qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

Then handle the change event in my `MainWindow` class:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "Change event";
   if(event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
   {
      qDebug() << "Language Change event";
      ui->retranslateUi(this);
   }

   QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}
```

The `retranslateUi()` function is called from the `ui_mainwindow.h`, but the UI isn't updated with the correct language, the localisation is definitely loaded according to the debug statements. Translation definitely works as I store the selected value as a `QSettings` value and check it on application load, and restarting the application does translate it correctly so I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: I hope that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224101/how-to-translate-language-in-qt-on-the-fly) will you. It's about the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

It turns out the problem doesn't come from the `retranslateUi()` method, nor the `MainWindow::changeEvent()` method, but from the way `QTranslator`s are handled:

You need to call:

```cpp
application->removeTranslator(previousTranslator);
```

Before:

```cpp
application->installTranslator(translator);
```