# PySide: Dynamically change language at runtime without ui.retranslateUi

Tags: qt, dynamic, runtime, translation, pyside

I have a simple programm where i want to switch languages at runtime.
Since the GUI is not done with QtDesigner i dont have a .ui file and thus cannot use ui.retranslateUi as far as i can see. My current way of solving this is manually calling setText on every Widget every time a language change event occurs:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys


class Simple(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('translate-me')
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.clicked.connect(self.switchLanguage)
        self.show()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.LanguageChange:
            self.setText(self.tr('translate-me'))

    def switchLanguage(self):
        self.translator.load('translation-file')
        QApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
simple = Simple()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The solution with using ui.retranslateUi as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10224592/3798964) is much shorter though. Is there a solution similar to that when not using a .ui
file for the GUI?

Comment: It's probably not worth it. You can allow the user to change languages, and then give them an option to restart the application. `retranslateUi` doesn't magically fix everything, every use of `tr()` in your code will need to be audited to ensure it will update any visible strings when the languages change. This is usually hard to do unless you are just starting the development - and then you'll have to design some sort of a common pattern to implement it that every piece of your code that uses user-visible string will have to adhere to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `retranslateUi` method only affects objects created from the `ui` file. So in order for it to provide a *complete* solution, every single string needing re-translation would have to be set in the ui file. Any strings added elsewhere would need entirely separate handling.

Here is an example of the `retranslateUi` method:

```
def retranslateUi(self, Window):
    self.fileMenu.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "&File", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.helpMenu.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "&Help", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.fileQuit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "&Quit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.fileQuit.setShortcut(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "Ctrl+Q", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.helpAbout.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "&About", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.helpAboutQt.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Window", "About &Qt", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

As you can see, all it does is call `setText` (or whatever) on the affected objects it knows about. There is no magic involved. It's just boiler-plate code generated by the `pyside-uic` tool.

If you can't use a `ui` file, you will have to create something equivalent to the above yourself.